# Change the order of properties inside a PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I know it's kinda weird question, but I have this "problem".
I'm creating game middleware for creating realistic lighting with global illumination and whatever.

I'm at the stage of creating a world viewer, where you can view the world, make some changes to it, see how the lightmaps look like, you know.

There is a property grid in it. In mesh class, I have a meshdata property, and in meshdata property I have material property, and in that material property I have COLOR PROPERTY. YEAH.
It has R G B properties.
When I view the color property in property grid, order of those values is like BGR, can I change it to RGB?

Lol I write definitely too much..

Answer (score 0):

What type is your Color property? 
If you can you should use System.Windows.Media.Color structure as your property type.

Since you need float data to represent each color look at the definition of System.Windows.Media.Color

```
    public float ScA { get; set; }        
    public float ScB { get; set; }       
    public float ScG { get; set; }
    public float ScR { get; set; }

    public static Color FromScRgb(float a, float r, float g, float b);
    public static Color FromAValues(float a, float[] values, Uri profileUri);
    public float[] GetNativeColorValues();
    public static Color FromValues(float[] values, Uri profileUri);
```

Comment: Yes but is there a good reason not to use the type I have mentioned?

Comment: Yep, Media.Color uses R G B as bytes, I need to use them as floats.

Comment: Please look at my edited answer. I won't comment anymore on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **PropertyOrder** attribute along with your **PropertySorter**.
Create PropertySorter class inherited from ExpandableObjectConverter and override GetPropertiesSupported and GetProperties methods to define your own sorting order.

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(PropertySorter))]
public class ColorProperty
{
    [PropertyOrder(1)]
    public int R { get; set; }
    [PropertyOrder(2)]
    public int G { get; set; }
    [PropertyOrder(3)]
    public int B { get; set; }
}
```